# Who can see an internal/private blog?

Tags: blog

My company is looking to start an internal company blog that only our employees have access to. We are looking at Sharepoint and other options to do this, (one of which is WordPress). Not everyone in our office has Sharepoint.

If an employee doesn't have Sharepoint on their computer, could they see the blog?  I read something that implied that there are options for people without Sharepoint to add to a blog (such as through email), but I couldn't find how one would access a private blog.

And if anyone has enough knowledge to compare, what would the pros and cons be for Sharepoint vs WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharepoint is a web site, so if all users have a browser, they can get to the blog. Sharepoint blogs are permissions based, so owners have the ability to control who has access to view, author, and comment.

Sharepoint is going to give you so much more organizationally than wordpress that we could go on for days. Wordpress is strictly a blogging site where as Sharepoint is a collaboration system which has a blog component to it.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  If I don't have Sharepoint, how easy would it be for me to take a leading role in setting up such a blog?  Would it even be possible?

Comment: There is a lot that goes into getting Sharepoint up and running, it can be installed on a Windows 7 machine for testing and development where you could then create your own blog. Ideally your IT department would provision a Sharepoint environment and grant you access to a site where you can create a blog.